# Prove that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Phi(- \sqrt{n})}{f(\sqrt{n})} = 1$.

Tags: limits, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be standard normal random variable. Let $\Phi$ be a distribution function of $X$ and $f$ density function of $X$. Prove that $$  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\Phi(- \sqrt{n})}{f(\sqrt{n})} = 1$$.

This question is a part of task. But I don't have any idea hot show this limes. I will grateful for yours help.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

The result you ask to show is doubtful, since $$\frac{\Phi(-x)}{\varphi(x)}=\mathrm e^{x^2/2}\int_x^\infty\mathrm e^{-t^2/2}\mathrm dt\stackrel{t=x+s}{=}\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-s^2/2}\mathrm e^{-xs}\mathrm ds\leqslant\int_0^\infty\mathrm e^{-xs}\mathrm ds=\frac1x\to0,\ \text{when}\ x\to+\infty.$$ On the other hand, $$x\frac{\Phi(-x)}{\varphi(x)}\to1,\ \text{when}\ x\to+\infty.$$

Comment: But wolfram tell: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+%28n-%3Einfinity%29+%280.5*%281+%2B+erf%28-sqrt%28n%2F2%29%29%29*sqrt%282*pi*n%29+*+exp%28n%2F2%29

Comment: Try lim (n->infinity) (0.5*(1 + erf(-sqrt(n/2)))*sqrt(2*pi*n) * exp(n/2) in wolfram alpha.

Comment: I think you have lost $x$ before integral...

Comment: Why the factor sqrt(2.pi.n)? The variance is 1 hence there the prefactor of the PDF is 1/sqrt(2.pi), not 1/sqrt(2.pi.n). If you can be more specific about where I would have "lost x before integral", please be, otherwise I fail to see the point.